# how to handle displayed text in a select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to display only part of the selected option:

```
const refertiItems = this.state.referti.map((referti, i) => {
  return (
    <option key={referti.hash_referto} >
  [ {referti.proprietario} - {referti.tipo_esame} - {referti.data_esame.split('T')[0]} ] {referti.hash_referto}
    </option>
  )
});
```

and then

```
        Label for="type" text="Seleziona un referto (proprietario - tipo esame - data)" />
        <select
          name="careGiver"
          placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
          onKeyPress={this.onEnter}
          value={this.codiceReferto}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        >
          <option default value="vuoto" />
          {refertiItems}
        </select>
```

When i select an option, i want to be displayed only {referti.proprietario} and {referti.tipo_esame}, but not {referti.hash_referto}. 
I can't just take it off from the option.

Any advice?

Comment: If this is React code or JSX with some other framework (or just JSX on its own), please tag it accordingly.

Comment: So when the `select` is closed, you want it to show one thing, but when it's open you want it to show something else...? That's what this sounds like. Unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to do that with a standard `select`, since although you mostly get an event when the select is closed (`click` or `input`), you don't necessarily get one when it's opened (and if you do, it's `click` and doesn't tell you whether that means opened or closed). You'll have to live with the additional text when the option is selected, live it not having that text in the list, or do something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You most definitely can update the text. You can do this by updating your state array when an item is selected to present the appropriate display text. This is just a rough example, but the concept of how it could be done is shown:

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef
} = React;

function App() {
  const [opts, setOpts] = useState([{
      label: 'one',
      active: 'one',
      inactive: 'one remove_me'
    },
    {
      label: 'two remove_me',
      active: 'two',
      inactive: 'two remove_me'
    },
    {
      label: 'three remove_me',
      active: 'three',
      inactive: 'three remove_me'
    },
  ]);

  return (<div>
      <select onChange={({target: {value}})=>{
          // There are better ways to deep copy, should look into replacing this
          let deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(opts)).map(e=>{
            e.label = e.active==value?e.active:e.inactive;
            return e;
          });
          setOpts(deepCopy);
        }}>
        {opts.map(o=>
            <option key={o.active} value={o.active}>{o.label}</option>)}
      </select>
    </div>); 
}

const el = document.querySelector("#app");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```